# How can I make a directory accessible without putting it on a menu?

Tags: url, .htaccess-configuration, file-permissions, download

I want users to be able to download a file from my Joomla website, but I don't want the URL posted anywhere on my site. **How can I make a file downloadable without adding any links to it from my site?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Obfuscated File Name**

You can upload a file to the website e.g. at website.com/obfuscatedfilename.pdf and then notify users of the file location via email.

Users can then download the file by browsing directly to it and selecting the option to download the file.

**Restricted Content**

You could add the link to an article and only allow access to the article for registered users. Create accounts only for users that need access to the file.

You could implement a similar solution using a third party download manager extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apache, you can also make a directory indexable by editing the .htaccess file in that directory.

Just make a file in your directory called `.htaccess`. The file should contain the following (and whatever other apache options you want):

```
Options +Indexes
```